# How to save a re-ordered queryset to database in Django

Tags: python, django

For example,
I have a model

```
class Question(models.Model):
question_text = models.TextField()
question_number = IntegerField(default=0)
```

I try to do:

```
question_list = Question.objects.order_by('question_number')
#then save the queryset back to the database
```

How should I do that?

Comment: You can't... your database doesn't store querysets, it stores individual rows of data. A queryset is the result of querying the database. What are you trying to achieve here? Are you trying to [set the default ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#ordering) of data returned from your model?

Comment: Why would you want to that ? If you want questions to be ordered by question_number just order using same order_by while fetching.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the fetch operation. Try this

```
question_list = Question.objects.all().order_by("-question_number") # DESC order
```

or

```
question_list = Question.objects.all().order_by("question_number") # ASC order
```

Also if you want to save, have to try this

```
for question in question_list:
    #Update any field here
    question.save()
```

Comment: Django doesn't need a "fetch" operation, the majority of its queryset operations are done lazily